# Which file of Darknet (YOLO) I need to change to light the LED

Tags: c++, yolo, darknet

I make project with YOLO-V4 and Nvidia Jetson Nano. I want to light the LED on Jetson Nano if there is any detection from webcam stream. I could 100% successed it with python file that I made. But it works on CPU, not GPU and flows so slow.

Standart darknet way leads me to run the command;
./darknet detector demo cfg/yolov4.cfg yolov4.weights

So, which c++ files in darknet folder and which part of file I have to work on for coding about when there is a detection led=HIGH ...

Or if you have other suggestions I'd be happy to see
thanks..

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Sir, I downloaded darknet (YOLO) from https://github.com/AlexeyAB/darknet. And I can perform objeck detection with my Nvidia jetson nano. I want to light up led with Jetson nano I/O pin when a sport ball detected. I have codes for light the led but I don't know which file of darknet I need to code in it. Thank you